# Map point class diversity on raster efficiently in R

Tags: raster, r, point

I have a point data set of roughly 2'000 features that represent User GPS locations. I'd like to calculate the User diversity per pixel. This is a (very slow) Pseudocode:

```
library(raster)
library(sp)

pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(someQuery)
rast <- RasterLayer(someQuery) # Defines empty raster pixels

for (pixel in pixels) {
    1. Get point subset pts_sub within distance d from pixel center
    2. Get user_diversity of pts_sub (eg nUsers / nPts)
    3. Set pixel value to user_diversity
}
```

The following image illustrates the situation. For the upper left pixel, all pts within the blue circle have to be subset and the diversity index is calculated from these.

[image: Points and Raster]

The procedure has to be applied to many more datasets, therefore I need a faster way to do this. The "calc"-function of the raster package allows custom functions on raster, but doesn't allow to access the pixel coordinates. Is there a fast way to apply such a function to pixels of a raster?

Comment: Can you compute the full distance matrix of points to grid cell centres? Or is that way too large? It'll be 2000 x number of grid cells.

Comment: One raster is around 700x700 = 490'000 pixels. Some spatial indexing would be good.